# Firebase onDatachange() to set value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to set the value using onDataChange() in Firebase? I do not know the value of the post key of each child.

[Posts database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFN67.jpg)

```
databaseReference2 = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts");

Query query2 = databaseReference2.orderByChild("userID").equalTo(currentUser.getUid());

query2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot snap:snapshot.getChildren())
      {
       Post post = snap.getValue(Post.class);
       post.setPicture(image);
       post.setUserName(name);
      }
     }  
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
    
     }
   });
```

Comment: Where do you want to put the value of `snapshot`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying , I just want to update the image and name of each posts when users edited his profile name and image but I do not know the key of each posts. Every posts has a  ("userID"), so I thought I can refer to that and update the name and image of each post.

Comment: Can you post your database structure and tell us which key you are talking too. I was thinking about `snap.getKey()`

Comment: Ok , sorry to make you confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the value using onDataChange() in firebase?

Yes, it is.

> I do not know the value of the post key of each child.

Actually, there is no need for that.

> I just want to update the image and name of each post when users edited their profile name and image.

To achieve that, please use the following lines of code:

```
databaseReference2 = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts");
Query query2 = databaseReference2.orderByChild("userID").equalTo(currentUser.getUid());
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
            update.put("picture", image);
            update.put("userName", name);
            postSnapshot.getRef().updateChildren(update).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getkey()` in `ondatachange` This will give you the keys you are talking to

```
for(DataSnapshot snap:snapshot.getChildren())
  {
   String keys = snap.getKey();
  }
```